# Ansible remote provisioning vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm using an ansible remote server to provision my production server, that works well.
Now I thought about using this ansible server to provision my vagrant VMs.

Is this possible somehow? I thought about a shell script provision for the vagrant file that logs into the ansible server via ssh and executes the playbook command towards the VM on the local machine.

I don't have too much experience with shell scripts. Has anybody tried this or can tell me a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not just run Ansible as proper Vangrant provisioner?

Answer (score 1):

As [Mxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949859/mxx) wrote the best way would be to configure Vagrant box in a way to provision it using Ansible from the local machine. Then you would just need to type `vagrant up [name of the box]` and this would start the machine and provision it. Below I'am attaching a simple example of provisioning Vagrant box using Ansible, you can find all details concerning Ansible provisioner [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html).

```rb
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

# Example of vagrant box provisioned using Ansible
# Start box: "vagrant up dev"
config.vm.define "dev" do |dev|
  dev.vm.box = "Centos-6.5-minimal-x86_64-20140116"
  dev.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.3/centos65-x86_64-20140116.box"

  dev.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize [
                    "modifyvm", :id,
                    "--name", "example-vagrant-box",
                    "--memory", 1024,
                    "--cpus", 2,
                ]
  end
  dev.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.1"
  dev.vm.hostname = "vagrant.local"

  # Provision the box using Ansible provisioner
  dev.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    # Path to the inventory file
    ansible.inventory_path = "./inventories/local"
    # Path to playbook that should be run against the machine
    ansible.playbook = "someplaybook.yml"
    # Provisioning verbosity level
    # "v", "vv", "vvv", "vvvv". 4 x v for the most verbose debugging info
    ansible.verbose = "vvvv"
    # Limit provisioning to the following groups
    # This defines all the servers (or server groups) which should be provisioned to
    # These are defined in the inventory file.
    ansible.limit = ["db_servers"]

    # Determines whether Ansible ask for Ansible Vault password when provisioner encounter encrypted file
    # ansible.ask_vault_pass = "true"
    # Optionally Ansible Vault password can be stored in the seperate file and passed like this
    ansible.vault_password_file = "./vault-password"
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes I know that I could do that, but I want to keep it open for windows which doesn't support ansible :/

Comment: From Ansible 1.7 you are able to provision Windows machine via PowerShell instead of SSH, for further details see here: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_windows.html . Although Windows based machine cannot be an Ansible control machine, so you cannot provision local/remote machine from Windows. You can create VM with some lightweight Linux distribution on Windows and provision everything from it, but this is really pointless. Windows just is not a good development environment.

Comment: I know it's possible to provision windows machines. I wanted to work from a windows host. But I started to ate it so I switched to a Linux machine now. The thing was only if it's possible. So if somebody comes to the team and can use this povision server without installing ansible and can work that way.